# Ordinals and initial segments

Tags: set-theory, ordinals, well-orders

If $W(\zeta)$ is an initial segment of an ordinal $\beta$ then can I be sure that $\zeta \in \beta$?

Is this definitely true?

Comment: An ordinal being a well-ordered set in which each element equals its initial segment

Comment: What is $W(\zeta)$ (as opposed to $\zeta$)?

Comment: $W(\zeta)=\{x\in \beta : x < \zeta\}$

Comment: But that's just $\zeta\cap\beta$ (remember that for ordinals "$\in$" and "$<$" are the same).

Comment: Also, by "initial segment" do you mean "*proper* initial segment"? (Otherwise consider $\zeta=\beta$ ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any **proper** initial segment of an ordinal is an element of that ordinal. (Obviously the whole ordinal itself is an initial segment which isn't an element of itself.)

Specifically, suppose $\alpha$ is an ordinal and $\Theta\subseteq\alpha$ is a proper initial segment of $\alpha$. Let $\theta$ be the least element of $\alpha$ not in $\Theta$. Then we have $\theta=\Theta$ (by the definition of ordinals) and $\theta\in\alpha$.